# Append Fragment on first click then remove on second in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So here's what I'm trying to do, I have a button that I want to add an external HTML fragment when it is clicked for the first time. Then have that same fragment removed when that same button is clicked a second time. I'm very new to jQuery so I've been having trouble with this.

You can view the full code here: http://jsfiddle.net/jhoffm34/6xLw8/ , but here's the jQuery code I have so far. I know I'm going about this the wrong way, but I don't know how to fix it.

```
$.get("fragment.html", function(data) {
    $('.js-load__button').click(function(){
        $('#js-load').append(data);
        $('.js-load__button').addClass("js-load__remove");
        $('.js-load__button').attr("disabled", true);
    });
    $('.js-load__remove').click(function(){
        $(data).remove();
        $('.js-load__button').attr("disabled", false);
    });
});
```

Comment: Try jQuery toggle event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code is a bit messy. If you organize things a little differently, it becomes pretty straightforward.

First. a more simplified HTML:

```
<ul id="list">
    <li>
        <figure>
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200"/>
            <figcaption>I Can Haz Kitty?</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </li>
    <li>
        <figure>
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200"/>
            <figcaption>I Can Haz Kitty?</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </li>
</ul>
<button>LOAD MORE</button>
```

Then here's the scripting to go along with it:

```
var list = document.getElementById('list');
var htmlFragment = '<li class="more"><figure><img src=\"http://placekitten.com/300/200\"/><figcaption>I Can Haz Kitty?</figcaption></figure></li>';

$('button').click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();

    var more = $(list).find('li.more');

    if (more.length > 0) {
        more.each(function() { $(this).remove(); });
    } else {
        $(htmlFragment).appendTo($(list));
    }
});
```

Because I don't have access to your AJAX call, I just assume some sort of HTML string is returned as 'htmlFragment'.

I forked your fiddle and updated it here: http://jsfiddle.net/ToddT/XHNrM/

Comment: That's perfect thanks! Appreciate you simplifying it.